# Android Market Topics offline documentation

Tags: android

Does anyone add Android Market Topics from developer.android.com to offline SDK docs? For using them without Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I haven't heard of anyone doing this. I guess theoretically anything's possible,  but if you did this than keeping them up to date may be an issue, because it changes fairly regularly.